# Streaming flash video does not work on my Mac OS X

Tags: macos, video, flash, streaming, embedded

Flash videos do not work properly on my Mac. On [this Vimeo video](http://vimeo.com/8121722), for example, it shows only the beginning frame, and audio stutters like crazy, playing audio for a quarter second or so, then silence, then playing again, etc.

I have Flash version 10,0,42,34 on Mac OS 10.5.8. It's a PowerBook G4 (PPC). I tried it in Firefox 3.5.5 and Safari 4.0.3.

I tried reinstalling Flash, restarting the computer, and using a fresh user profile in Firefox (so that no extensions are interfering with the site), loading the video fully before playing, but nothing helps.

I noticed that youtube videos work better, once loaded enough, although the picture does halt briefly once every 10 or so seconds, even when it's fully loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Flash performance is terrible on PPC with version 10. I don't have very good performance on a G5, and a G4 is rather old to be expecting any sort of decent performance on Flash. There are three options:

1. Adobe has to make improvements in Flash's performance. This one isn't going to happen.
2. You can buy an Intel Mac.
3. You can downgrade to Flash 9. You lose some security updates as Adobe is no longer updating version 9, but version 9 does perform better on PPC. I don't recommend this option.

Comment: My 933Mhz G4 sucks at most Flash video. I use ClickToFlash (http://rentzsch.github.com/clicktoflash/) to block most Flash and occasionally download/play H.264 from YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Firefox by any chance? The picture halting briefly every ten seconds reminds me of [a known issue with Firefox saving its session information](http://lifehacker.com/5342636/how-to-fix-annoying-youtube-jumpiness-in-firefox).

Answer (score 1):

One other partial fix:

Right-click a video while it is playing and choose the 'settings' menu for Adobe Flash player. From there, **uncheck** *"Use Hardware Acceleration"* on the Display tab, and bump the "Local Storage" tab slider bar up to 10MB.

(Found [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=768766) and it improved things for me, a little.)